# Не работает mouseEvent'ы в QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

У меня есть кастомный `QQuickWindow` (`CWindow`), в котором реализованы все mouseEvent'ы. Так же есть кастомный `QQuickItem` (`CItem`) в котором также есть `mouseEvent`'ы. Но вот в чем проблема, CWindow забирает все ивенты в том месте где находится `CItem` себе и в итоге `CItem` никак не реагирует. Как это можно исправить?
Классы все регистрирую функцией `qmlRegisterType<>()`

Comment: `MouseArea` поверх `CItem` положить и там в Qml обрабатывать как вариант не подойдёт ?

Comment: Нет, нужно чтобы именно в с++ event'ы были.

Comment: В конструкторе вашего `CItem` попробуйте `setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton)` и по кликайте левой кнопкой мыши

Comment: Уже пробывал. Не работает. Может есть у вас какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: У меня работает =) А пример тут Вы должны предоставлять. У меня правда обычный Window (не кастомный), и евенты только press/release при клике отрабатывают. До setAcceptedMouseButtons не отрабатывали. может и в Window надо этот setAcceptedMouseButtons вызвать ?

Comment: setAcceptedMouseButtons нет у QQuickWindow. Я проверил работает ли отдельно мой CItem, и да он работает. Но как только подключаю свой CWindow, то тут же он не работает. Сигналы идут только к ниму. И вот это проблема.

Comment: И да, MouseArea тоже перестает работать.